# Python: The Replacements

Tags: python, list

I'm currently trying to complete Computer Science Circles online but I am stuck on [part 14: Methods](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/14-methods/). Here is the question.

> Using `index` and other list methods, write a function `replace(list, X, Y)` which replaces all occurrences of `X` in `list` with `Y`. For example, if `L = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]` then `replace(L, 1, 7)` would change the contents of `L` to `[3, 7, 4, 7, 5, 9]`. To make this exercise a challenge, you are not allowed to use `[]`.
>
> Note: you don't need to use return.

I would probably be able to do this if we were allowed to use square brackets.
Here is what I have so far.

```
def replace(L, X, Y):
   while X in L:
      var = L.index(X)
      var = Y
   return(L)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect you need to be clear on what you're asking. What exactly is your question?

Comment: can I use [`operator.getitem` and `operator.setitem`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem)?

Comment: How do I replace the X value in the list with the Y value

Comment: The tables in the [sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) and [mutable sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) sections of the documentation are a good place to start.

Comment: That's your *homework*. What's your *question*? See [ask].

Comment: I realize it's not your fault (since it's in the problem description), but it's a very bad idea to use names of builtins like `list` as variable or parameter names. Doing so shadows the name, so in your function you won't be able to call `list` to make a new list (if you need to). You'll often see lists named `lst` or `L` for this reason (but not lower case `l`, which can look too much like a `1` in some fonts).

Comment: My question is exactly what I asked. How do I replace a certain value that is in a list with another certain value without using square brackets

Comment: The reason you were downvoted is probably because your question, instead of asking a question, is just a copy-paste of the assignment with a dump of your current code. It's kind of like walking up to someone at the library, putting your half-finished homework on top of their book, and waiting for them to finish it for you. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Blckknght - Ironically, passing a generator to `list()` is probably the easiest way to do this.

Comment: "My question is exactly what I asked." - Note that you didn't even actually ask that. You just inserted the text of the assignment, followed by your half-finished attempt, without even a description of what error or undesired output you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give some tips since this is an exercise.

1) You already found out the index where you're supposed to replace one element with another. What other way is there to replace a value in a given index? Check [all the methods of `list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

2) A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) also allows an elegant solution:

```
[...???... for value in list]
```

You'll need to figure out what the expression should be, and how to make the comprehension modify your original list, not just create a new one.

Comment: I think 2 is out: "you are not allowed to use []".

Comment: uhm... I think he said to avoid using `return`, so how would the list comprehension be used?

Comment: @Pynchia - Slice assignment would work. But the assignment forbids square brackets, anyway.